# Android custom multiple textviews

Tags: android, textview

I want to make something like image below, multiple `TextView` where the view goes to next line if it doesn't fit in the last line.
[image]

Does anybody have a suggestion how to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FlowLayout. Check this :- https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout

It also supports RTL layout

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no solution in Android SDK for such behavior, but you may write this by own (measuring text, if not fitting place `View` in next row). its not an easy task, so I would recommend [FlexBox lib](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 0):

The image you are showing is a ChipGroup with chips, not textviews. If you want to implement what you are seeing there, just create a chipgroup and add as many chips as you need, they will be set automatically on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

//Flex Layout for Custom layouts

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.0'
```

Use this library for this layout design.

You can create chips using XML code as well as programmatically.

```
var chip: Chip = Chip(this)
        chip.setText(name)
        chip.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

        val typeface =
            ResourcesCompat.getFont(
                this,
                R.font.lato_semibold
            )
        chip.setTypeface(typeface)
        chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                this,
                R.color.color_skyblue
            )
        )

        chip.setPadding(Global.dpToPx(this, 15f), 0, Global.dpToPx(this, 15f), 0)

        chip.chipCornerRadius = 40f

        var param: LinearLayout.LayoutParams? =
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
        chip.layoutParams = param

        flexLayoutSkills.addView(chip)
```